# Task Scheduler in c#

Tags: c#, scheduling

I would like to schedule threads like the Task Scheduler 2.0 only problem that I cannot use task scheduler is that it is registered at os level not the program level. Is there any way to use the task scheduling api to invoke thread creation with in program?

Comment: @Khan i think you can do this by creating window service

Comment: let me rephrase, with in a windows service i will have multiple code blocks to execute, that i will place in seperate procedures. i need to schedule each procedure differently like task schedular 2.0 api i-e daily, weekly, monthly etc

Comment: Are you probably looking for [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up pushing my own scheduling api very much like task schedular that will schedule threads not processes

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).

This allows you to specify a delegate to be invoked at a given time.

Comment: I think Timer will execute in a specified interval whereas he wants it to execute at a certain time and date. It is possible that his app is closed and opened again. The interval will need to be recalculated then. Another dowside is that Timer will not take into account day light saving.

Comment: @eypo - Timer can be set to signal only once after a given interval with no repitition (using Timeout.Infinite - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx). You make a valid point about loss of schedule between app instances, although this could be avoided, for instance  by persisting the current schedule in the file system. Daylight saving - indeed, this will be an issue. It may better to look into something like Quartz.net as per the comments.

Comment: @eypo - having thought about this a little more - daylight saving should not be an issue since the interval until the execution should be calculated as the difference of the desired datetime and the current datetime, which _should_ take into account daylight saving. Then, so long as the schedule is persisted to the file system when set, and checked and rescheduled after app shutdown and restart, the Timer based solution should work as desired.

Comment: as far as I understand daylight saving they are not deterministic. "For example, in 2008 most DST-observing areas shifted clocks forward on October 5 but Western Australia shifted on October 26." This is from wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: @evpo - I would expect the OS to provide this, with the .NET framework presenting it accordingly according the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, so that when finding the difference between two dates, daylight saving is respected. However, I wouldn't be surprised if the implementation wasn't up to scratch ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution is to check the time and date (say every minute). It will not take much CPU resources but the execution time will not be accurate to a second.